# Definition of a General Plane in a Projective Space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, definition

Definition 11.2 in Joe Harris's *Algebraic Geometry: A First Course* is the following.

> The **dimension** of an irreducible quasi-projective variety $X\subseteq P^n$ is the smallest integer $k$ such that a general $(n-k-1)$-plane $\Lambda\subseteq P^n$ is disjoint from $X$.

I am unable to follow what the author means by a "general" $(n-k-1)$-plane (apart from the vague intuitive meaning). I tried to look at the index but there is no mention of the word "general". Can somebody throw some light on what is the definition trying to say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planes of codimension $k+1$ are parametrized by $G(n-k,n+1)$. So the statement means if there is a non-empty Zariski open $U$ so that for all $\Lambda \in U$, $\Lambda$ is disjoint from $X$.

Comment: Thanks. What does the notation $G(n-k, n+1)$ mean? Is it the Grassmannian of all the $(n-k)$-dimensional planes in $\mathbb C^{n+1}$. Sorry I am new to algebraic geometry.

Comment: No worries ! Exactly. Sometimes you also see the notation $\Bbb G(n-k-1, n)$ which is the Grassmanian of projective $(n-k-1)$ linear subspaces of $\Bbb P^n$ (of course they are the same objects).

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. I think you did a really good choice, I really like the writing style of Harris :-)